# Write a program that prints out the first N emirps, five on each line, using python

Tags: python

An Emirp is a prime number whose reversal is also a prime number. For example, 17 is a prime and 71 is a prime, so 17 and 71 are emirps.

The following code compiles and accepts input. The input validation is correct but the program keeps running and does not output anything. I also wanted to know how it's possible to find errors in python. Please ignore indentation errors if there are any.

```
class negerror(UserWarning):
    pass


while True:

    prompt = input('Please enter a positive number: ')
    try:
        number=int(prompt)
        if number<=0:
            raise negerror
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('You did not enter an integer. Please try again. ')
    except negerror:
        print('You entered a negative number. Please make sure to enter a positive number')

def isPrime(value):
    count=0
    for i in range(1,value+1):
        if value%i==0:
            count=count+1
    if count<=2:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def reverse(value):
    val=str(value)
    val=val[::-1]
    val=int(val)
    return val


Test=2
countemirps=0
numberinoneline=0
while countemirps<number:
    if isPrime(Test) and isPrime(reverse(Test)):
        print('%6s'%Test, end = '  ')
        countemirps=countemirps+1
        Test=Test+1
        numberinoneline=numberinoneline+1
        if numberinoneline%5==0:
            print('\n')
```

Comment: `Please ignore indentation errors if there are any` Python won't.

Answer (score 0):

Your `isPrime` function is off. It counts the number of divisors of `value` and stores it in variable `count`. However, you return `True` if `count>2` and `False` otherwise. It should be the other way around: a prime number has two divisors and composite numbers have more then two. So change the test to `count <= 2`. Even better and more pythonic, replace the last lines of that function with

```
return count <= 2
```

or perhaps

```
return count == 2
```

Do you see why that works?

(I see that you have now corrected this error and edited your question but the program still does not work.)

---

Another error is that in your main loop you have the test

```
if isPrime(Test) and isPrime(reverse(Test)):
```

If that test is passed, you print the number and update your variables including `Test`--all is well. However, if the test fails you do *nothing*, and in particular the value of `Test` is not changed. The loop repeats and you do exactly the same test, and nothing changes. The program is stuck in an infinite loop.

You can fix this by moving the line that updates `Test` out of the `if` test and place it at the end of the loop so it is executed on each loop. Your loop then becomes

```
while countemirps<number:
    if isPrime(Test) and isPrime(reverse(Test)):
        print('%6s'%Test, end = '  ')
        countemirps=countemirps+1
        numberinoneline=numberinoneline+1
        if numberinoneline%5==0:
            print('\n')
    Test=Test+1
```

When I test your program now, it seems to work.

---

There may be other errors as well that I do not see. You should test function `isPrime` separately from the rest of your code. When that works well, then test function `reverse`. Then test sections of your code. Running your code all at once makes it difficult to localize and find errors.

---

Finally, you ask "how it's possible to find errors in Python". This is too broad a question for this site--you should read a book chapter or a tutorial on debugging. But in brief, there are two main approaches for beginners. The first is to liberally put `print` statements in your code, showing the flow of the program execution and the values of your key variables. If you had place the statement

```
print(Test)
```

at the beginning of your loop, you would have seen that the loop was repeating indefinitely and the value of `Test` was not changing. When the errors seem to be gone, you can remove or comment-out the `print` statements. Logging can do this a bit more easily

Another, better approach is to use a debugger. I do most of my Python programming in `Spyder`, a development environment which includes a debugger. I used that to execute your program one line at a time, and one window in `Spyder` showed my the values of your variables. There also are debuggers that work outside a development environment. I encourage you to find, learn, and use an Integrated Development Environment that includes a debugger. `Spyder` is a free, excellent one that specializes in scientific programming. I use it for my mathematics programming.